# Automatic screen locking does not work on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I am running Kubuntu 20.04.

I have set screen lock to automatically kick in after 3 minutes. It does not.

What could be preventing this? Do I have to close all programs before automatic screen locking can work?

Comment: Hmm. I don't know what is causing this, but speaking as someone using Kubuntu 21.10, you shouldn't have to close all programs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your screensaver settings? Typically lock screen won't work if it's waiting for screen saver to activate. I had this problem on Xubuntu, not Kubuntu, however. I actually uninstalled the screensaver to get suspend to work (without locking, actually) but this seems like a similar situation.